# Suppress error from UI5 language assistance in UI5 XML View

Tags: visual-studio-code, sapui5, ui5-tooling

I am using UI5 language assistance extension for code completion in my XML views. I want to suppress one particular error message that it shows in my view. Is there a way to achieve this so that it stops complaining for this line?
[image]

Comment: Sure, I can but my question is more in general nature on how to suppress this kind of message in XML view. In this particular case, it says that MenuButton can't be part of navigationActions aggregation as it is not a type of Button but it works perfectly fine and client needs this to be at that place for mobile devices.